# Axios - Remove headers Authorization in 1 call only

Tags: vuejs2, axios, vuex

How can I remove the axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization only in 1 call?

I'm setting the default for all the calls to my domain but I have 1 call that I make on another domain and if the token is passed the call gives me an error, when there's no default Auth token saved everything works fine.

So what I'm trying to do is not pass the Auth in that specific call

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
    loadApiCoins({ commit }) {
        Vue.axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': '',
            },
        }).then(...)
    },
```

I also tried auth: {...} but that doesn't work either.
What's the solution?
Thanks

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Try the following

```
delete axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"];
// or which ever header you have to remove
```

Comment: but wouldn't this remove the auth for all requests? I still need to use the token for other requests that will happen very shortly after this specific one

Comment: Can you try this `transformRequest: [(data, headers) => {
    delete headers.common.Authorization
    return data
}]`

Comment: I am referring to the following issue on the github library -> [axios/issue](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/382)

Comment: That does seem to work! Status: 200 has never looked so great.
I'm mad that I spent a great deal of time going through Axios issues yesterday and didn't find that. lol

Comment: So this will keep the token for the other calls right?

Comment: Yes it should keep the token for other request. Make sure to use the `transform request` function only inside the request you want to modify the headers.

Comment: I hope my answers were of any help

Comment: Yes it will keep the tokens for other calls intact.!

Answer (score 49):

To send a request without:

- Modifying global `axios` defaults
- Creating a new `axios` instance

Change your request similarly to this:

```js
axios.get('http://example.com', {transformRequest: (data, headers) => {
    delete headers.common['Authorization'];
    return data;
  }
});
```

The answer I was looking for was posted in the comments of Apurva jain's answer, but hasn't been made an individual answer, so I've posted it separately for easy reference :)

Comment: You can also simply delete `headers.common` in the callback if you wish to remove all default headers

Comment: This answer uses a different syntax than Apurva jain's comment. 
`transformRequest: [(data, headers) => {     
        delete headers.common.Authorization     
        return data 
}]`

is an array and returns the data parameter. 
`transformRequest: (data, headers) => {
        delete headers.common['Authorization'];
}` 
is a function with no return value. 
The first format worked for me.

Comment: Thanks brianf - I’ve now updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 17):

if you already have a default 'Authorization' for all requests 
you can create an instance for that specific request

```
var instance = axios.create();
delete instance.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'];

instance.get("http://api.com");
```

Comment: This one works for me while `transformRequest` doesn't works.

Answer (score 6):

I got the same issue trying to query S3 with my web-service auth token. Fixed it with this.

```
axios.get("http://api.com", {
        headers:{ Authorization:""}
});
```

You can change the default headers to an empty string, this won't affect the common default headers. Though not entirely sure if all web services will ignore the empty string header.

Comment: Yeah but if you work with a service like aws this can be a problem

Answer (score 5):

`delete axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"];`
will solve the problem. But remember to **add the authorization header back**.

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution is to remove all common header from a new axios instance:

```js
const awsAxios = axios.create({
    transformRequest: (data, headers) => {
        // Remove all shared headers
        delete headers.common;
        // or just the auth header
        delete headers.common.Authorization;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
delete request.defaults.headers.common.Authorization
```

That `request` should be return of a `$axios.create()`

Answer (score 1):

To extend on  @phantomraa's answer, you might want to use

```js
this.$axios.$get(
      url, {
      // modify auth header for current request only
      transformRequest: (data, headers) => {
        // prevent the header from being added by default
        delete headers.common['Authorization'];
        // some libraries might set it directly as well, e.g. nuxtjs/auth
        delete headers['Authorization'];
        return data;
      }
})
```

Sorry, need a bit more rep to just comment.

Answer (score 0):

According to the latest axios [`Request Config` documentation](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config) we can use `transformRequest`:

> // This is only applicable for request methods 'PUT', 'POST', 'PATCH' and 'DELETE'
>
> // The last function in the array must return a string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer,
>
> // FormData or Stream
>
> // You may modify the headers object.

An example:

```js
axiosInstance.post('/api/auth-token', { email, password }, {
  transformRequest: [
    (data, headers) => {
      delete headers.common['Authorization'];
      return JSON.stringify(data);
    },
  ],
});
```

Please note the call to `JSON.stringify` as mentioned in the documentation, you need to return a `Buffer`, `ArrayBuffer`, `FormData` or `Stream`.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but with the latest axios, it's only `delete headers['Authorization'];`

Answer (score -1):

```
const mynewinstance = axios.create();
mynewinstance.defaults.headers.common = {};
const output = await mynewinstance.get(`https://google.com`);
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score -3):

delete axios.defaults.headers.common["language"];