# Axios post blocked by CORS. Using CLoudinary api

Tags: reactjs, axios, cors, fetch, cloudinary

I am trying to do a post request with axios to upload a image to cloudinary from my frontend React app. I am getting this error from the axios code below:

> http://localhost:3000 has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field x-access-token is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Using axios, doesnt work gives me cors error

```js
await axios({
  method: "POST",
  url: "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/******/image/upload/",
  data: {
    file: img,
    upload_preset: "*****",
    cloud_name: "****",
  },
})
  .then((res) => {
    console.log("response");
    console.log(res);
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Meanwhile when i use fetch using the same api request, the post request works and doesnt give me error. Anyone know why and how to call the api using axios?

```
  const data = new FormData();
        data.append("file", img);
        data.append("upload_preset", "*****");
        data.append("cloud_name", "*****");


  await fetch(
           "  https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/****/image/upload/",
           {
             method: "post",
             body: data,
           }
         )
           .then((resp) => resp.json())
           .then((data) => {
             setUrlArray((prevState) => [...prevState, data.url]);
           })
           .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Extra info: My upload preset is unsigned.
Also got this from the console after making the axios api call

```
{
error: {
message: "Upload preset must be specified when using unsigned upload"
}
}
```

Comment: I would check the headers in your dev tools and see what's different between the requests.

Comment: Axios uses the `data` property, **not** `body`. See [Request Config](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config#:~:text=data%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20firstName%3A%20%27Fred%27%0A%20%20%7D%2C)

Comment: Another difference is that your Axios request is sending JSON but your `fetch()` is sending `multipart/form-data`. If `fetch()` works for you, why not just use that instead of Axios?

Comment: I need to use axios because the codebase is using axios, and its required to be consistent. I also changed body to data still doesnt work. ;(

Comment: In your code, where does `axios` come from? Where is the `x-access-token` header coming from?

Comment: i am using axios from the import like you described below, nothing else. Idk why i get x-access token from header. This is the full cors  error----> error Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/CLOUDNAME/image/upload/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field x-access-token is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Comment: I found it. In one of the redux thunk file they have 
axios.interceptors.request.use(async function (config) {
  const token = await localStorage.getItem("messenger-token");
  config.headers["x-access-token"] = token;

  return config;
});

Comment: Also found one in the server file for nodejs. 
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  const token = req.headers["x-access-token"];
  if (token) {
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.SESSION_SECRET, (err, decoded) => {
      if (err) {
        return next();
      }
      User.findOne({
        where: { id: decoded.id },
      }).then((user) => {
        req.user = user;
        return next();
      });
    });
  } else {
    return next();
  }
});

Comment: What a bizarre interceptor. `localStorage.getItem()` is synchronous, there's no need for `await` there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create an Axios request equivalent to your working `fetch()` one, you need to

1. Craft a `FormData` instance and set it as the request `data` so your content-type is `multipart/form-data`
2. Make sure you're not using a previously [created Axios instance](https://axios-http.com/docs/instance) with unwanted default headers
3. If custom headers have been set on the default Axios instance, eg

   ```js
   axios.defaults.headers.common["x-access-token"] = TOKEN
   ```

   you may need to [override / delete them in `transformRequest`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62724928/283366)
4. To avoid any interceptors defined on the default Axios instance, create a new separate instance for un-intercepted requests

```js
import axios from "axios" // import the default instance

// create a new instance without interceptors. 
// you could also create this in its own module and import from there
const instance = axios.create()

const data = new FormData()
data.append("file", img);
data.append("upload_preset", "*****");
data.append("cloud_name", "*****");

const res = await instance.post(
  "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/******/image/upload/", 
  data
)
```

Ideally, if your app is going to customise requests, you should always use an Axios instance (or multiple instances) to avoid messing around with the defaults.

Comment: I already tried that and it didnt work :(

Comment: @dotaplayer tried _what_, exactly.

Comment: I tried ur code and the cors error still here but inside the link I dont get error: {
message: "Upload preset must be specified when using unsigned upload"
} anymore instead i get now message: error{"Upload preset must be whitelisted for unsigned uploads" }

Comment: @dotaplayer I've update my answer to show how to avoid default interceptors

Comment: thank u so much. it finally worked!!!!